# Datanucleus enhancer error: transient method

Tags: java, maven, jpa, datanucleus

I have a class

```
@Entity
public class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    ... 
    public boolean isOpenAt(Date x) {
        return true; // or whatever
    }
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.Field)
public abstract class BaseClass {
    ...
}
```

Running `mvn datanucleus:enhance` I get the error `org.datanucleus.metadata.InvalidClassMetaDataException: "MyClass.openAt" : declared in MetaData, but this field doesnt exist in the class!` Any idea why?

I'm using org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:3.2.7, org.datanucleus:datanucleus-accessplatform-jpa-rdbms:3.3.2, org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.1.0, org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:3.3.0-release.

Comment: that wouldn't compile, never mind enhance

Comment: Actually it compiled. Why do you say it wouldn't?

Comment: "cannot return a value from method whose result type is void"

Comment: Good catch. Wrong copy/paste on my side :). I changed the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I have no idea what datanucleus is.

That said, it's likely that `isOpenAt()` method gets treated as a getter (similar to `getFirstName()`, say), since according to According to the JavaBeans spec,

> **Boolean properties**
>
> In addition, for boolean properties, we allow a
>   getter method to match the pattern:
>
> `public boolean is<PropertyName>();`
>
> This "isPropertyName" method may be provided instead of a
>   "get" method, or it may be provided in addition to a
>   "get" method. In either case, if the is
>   method is present for a boolean property then we will use the
>   "is" method to read the property value. An example
>   boolean property might be:
>
> `public boolean isMarsupial(); public void setMarsupial(boolean m);`

Try renaming `isOpenAt()` into `seeIfOpenAt()` and see if that helps.